# DSL query to find the elements from array of dictionaries on multiple keys

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have a index in elastic search called `professor`

- If for cross field i need "AND" condition
- for same field array i need to OR condition

1. I need to search `BusinessArea` which is `Research` or `Accounting` this is array of fields(OR) statement

1.a `BusinessArea` has to check in `name` as well as `parentname`

AND

2. I need to search `Role` is `Developer` or `Tester` condition this is array of fields(OR) statement

   AND
3. I need to search `Location` is `NY`(&) condition

```
test=[ { 'id': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Accounting', 'parentname': 'Finance'}, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Research', 'parentname': 'R & D' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }, ] }, { 'id': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research', 'parentname': '' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }, ] }, { 'id': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Engineering', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' } ] } ]
```

Query is below, except

#1.a

```
content_search = es.search(index="professor", body={
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
       {
      "terms": 
          {
        "BusinessArea.name.keyword": ["Research","Accounting"]
          }
       },
     {
       "terms": 
              {
                "Role.name.keyword": ["Developer","Tested"]
              }
      }
  ]
},
  "filter": [
    {
      "term": {
        "Location.keyword": "NY"
      }
    }
  ]
```

}
})

Comment: looks like you missed few sentences , can you please make it clear by some example docs and your index mapping?

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja  basically for business area i need to check in 2 keys `name` and `parentname`

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja can i do `"BusinessArea.name.keyword": ["Research","Accounting"],"BusinessArea.parentname.keyword": ["Research","Accounting"]`

Comment: You can easily use the multi_match query easily :) , please refer this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html , will add a sample example in answer

Comment: Please add your mapping and sample data, so that I can provide example according to your data :)

Comment: You can use the multimatch in a bool query or use a copy_to field to do the And on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), with a combination of the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

The below search query will work for your 1(A) condition in such a way that, it searches for (`Research` OR `Accounting`) in `BusinessArea.name` AND `BusinessArea.parentname` field

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Research",
                  "fields": [
                    "BusinessArea.name.keyword",
                    "BusinessArea.parentname.keyword"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Accounting",
                  "fields": [
                    "BusinessArea.name.keyword",
                    "BusinessArea.parentname.keyword"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "Role.name.keyword": [
              "Developer",
              "Tester"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
  {
    "_index": "64572999",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1.7587298,
    "_source": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Group1",
      "BusinessArea": [
        {
          "id": "14",
          "name": "Research",
          "parentname": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Accounting",
          "parentname": ""
        }
      ],
      "Role": [
        {
          "id": "5032",
          "name": "Tester"
        },
        {
          "id": "5033",
          "name": "Developer"
        }
      ],
      "Designation": [
        {
          "id": "16",
          "name": "L1"
        },
        {
          "id": "20",
          "name": "L2"
        },
        {
          "id": "25",
          "name": "L2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "64572999",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 1.167868,
    "_source": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Group1",
      "BusinessArea": [
        {
          "id": "14",
          "name": "Research"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Engineering",
          "parentname": ""
        }
      ],
      "Role": [
        {
          "id": "5032",
          "name": "Developer"
        },
        {
          "id": "5033",
          "name": "Developer",
          "parentname": ""
        }
      ],
      "Designation": [
        {
          "id": "16",
          "name": "L1"
        },
        {
          "id": "20",
          "name": "L2"
        },
        {
          "id": "25",
          "name": "L2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```